# How to get the full current URL in PHP with the query string and parse it?

Tags: php, url

I've went through tons of websites and a few pages of StackOverflow however I just can't find somethting that works.

So, what I'm trying to do is get the current URL of the page with the query strings so I can parse it, but it doesn't work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my current code:

```php
$url = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";  
$CurPageURL = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);
$id = $params['id'];
```

Here is where I'm using that $id variable later on:

```html
<h3 class="t"><?=$id?>, please enter your staff password below.</h3>
```

No errors are being thrown, please help!, Thanks!

Comment: Where is `$url_components` being set? What is its value?

Comment: Where is `$protocol` being set? Errors/Warnings are not showing because you have error reporting off

Comment: Is my information useful for you?

Comment: @Bratslavskij Though I no longer need this, it did work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

```
<?php
$br       = "<br>";
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']), 'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$hostame  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if ($params == ""){
    $currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $hostame . $script . $params;
}
else {
    $currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $hostame . $script . '?' . $params;
}
?>

URL: <?php echo $currentUrl . $br; ?>
Protocol: <?php echo $protocol . $br; ?>
Hostname: <?php echo $hostame . $br; ?>
<?php 
if ($script == ""){ 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Page / Script: " . $script . $br; };
if ($params == ""){
    exit; 
} else { 
    echo "Params: " . $params . $br; }; 
?>
```

Comment: Maybe it works on **PHP 7.4.0** or higher

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` will return **HTTP/1.1**, or **HTTP/2.0**. It is not use to indicate https.